# Book about a glass world behind a mirror

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

There was this book that I read when I was young, maybe like 11 years old. A girl went into the mirror in her bedroom and found this world made entirely of glass. There were glass butterflies and stuff too.

I believe she meets a boy, but there is someone or something that doesn't want her there. The world is also dying/in trouble or something and it's turning black. I don't remember much other than I think a bunny dies, and in the end, a bunch of glass crushes the legs of the boy she's with and she has to abandon him to escape.

Another memory of this that's kind of fuzzy and maybe inaccurate is the girl gets stuck in the world for a while but she is able to see into the world through other mirrors/windows and it seems that a fake version of herself has taken her place back in the real world so her parents don't know she  is gone.

If you have any ideas please let me know! It was a pretty heavy theme/story for an 11-year-old and I've been wanting to read it again to see if there's any deeper meanings I missed back then.

Comment: when were you 11 years old? was the book aimed at a younger audience?

Comment: this might be slightly offtopic, but through a looking glass has alice go to wonderland through a mirror i believe. but thats all i know about it

Comment: @Himarm If the OP read that as a child, that would make the OP 150 years old!

Comment: Or, OP read an old book when they were 11...

Answer (score 6):

This *could* be one of the [books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MirrorMask#Other_media) based on the film [MirrorMask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MirrorMask):

> The film's story revolves around a young girl named Helena Campbell, who is sick of her family's career as circus performers. Helena's mother is hospitalized after they have an argument, and Helena finds herself trapped in a fantasy world shortly after.

Helena does not travel to the fantasy land through a mirror - instead,

> she wakes up in a dream-like state and leaves her building to find three performers outside. As they try to perform for Helena, a shadow encroaches on the area and two of the performers are consumed by it. The third performer, Valentine (Jason Barry), a juggler, helps to quickly direct Helena to safety through the use of magical flying books.

However, the titular mask *could* be the mirror element as remembered.

Further,

> the City of Light ... is slowly being consumed by shadows

and

> Helena discovers that by looking through the windows of the buildings, she can see into her bedroom in the real world, through the drawings of windows that she created and hung on the wall of her room. She discovers that a doppelganger of herself is living there and behaving radically different from her.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175670/fantasy-movie-with-black-and-white-queens (about the movie on which the books are based)

Answer (score 1):

It's been ages since I read it, so I might be remembering wrong, but parts of this description remind me of Steven R. Donaldson's [Mordant's Need series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordant's_Need), a 2 part series that's comprised of The Mirror of Her Dreams and A Man Rides Through. Some parts of the story fit your description, although like I said, it's been forever since I read it, so I'm not sure about the specific details. I do remember the mirrors into other worlds (which is what made me think of this series), and remember that it's excellently written. I also know I fell in love with Donaldson when I was about that age (I discovered Thomas Covenant and was forever hooked). :)

Comment: I like the covenant trilogies, but I didn't like much of donaldsons other stuff. I tried getting through some of them but ultimately put the other books down for good. The sci fo story with a guy named Thermopyle is about the only memory I have of those though.

Comment: It's not Mordant's Need. The world the woman falls into isn't made of glass. Mirrors in that world are used to do magic. Those interested can view [Wikipedia's summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordant's_Need).

Comment: @Escoce: I thought the first Covenant trilogy was great, but the second one was slow.  Same with the two Mordant's Need books. However, I enjoyed [The Gap Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gap_Cycle) - the books involving Angus Thermopylae and Morn Hyland.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a book, but Lost in Space had an [episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0636232/) that's practically identical to what you're describing.

Plot excerpt from [Wikia](http://lostinspace.wikia.com/wiki/The_Magic_Mirror):

> .... Later, Penny goes back the mirror in search of Debbie who has discovered a small bell somewhere. She eventually realizes that the bloop has been able to pass through the mirror somehow, and then return to the real world with the bell. Penny herself falls through the mirror and finds herself in a dark, mysterious world. There she meets a nameless boy about her own age who invites her to stay and have fun....