# Fantasy movie with black and white queens

Tags: story-identification, movie

Apologies for the probably unanswerable question.

I've only seen a brief scene of the movie, on TV around 1993-2000, where the heroes (a small group, around 4) planned to travel from the realm of the White Queen to the realm of the Black Queen (which was presumably evil), probably to disrupt her plans. The setting was fantasy/medieval.

Uncovered (The Flanders Panel) fits the white/black queen theme but I don't think it fits the medieval atmosphere.

Comment: MirrorMask? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swrcKRVgeGI

Comment: You mention a detail, "medieval atmosphere" in a rather backhanded fashion.  Are you sure you don't have other small details that you could add?  How many heroes?  Two?  Ten?  Hundreds?  How old?  Children?  Young adults?  Middle aged?  Senior citizens?  All male?  Mixed?

Comment: Red/White queens but is similar to Alice in Wonderland.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: you are thinking of [Through the Looking-Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass).

Comment: @Brythan good point, added it in the main description. Can't recall age/genders :(

Comment: @Valorum hm, looks similar, will check the full movie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Mirrormask](http://www.sonypictures.com/movies/mirrormask/index.html)* from 2005, written by Neil Gaiman.

> *The White Queen sleeps and will not wake. Black shadows have fallen
>   across her kingdom. The balance between Dark and Light is broken and
>   only the MIRRORMASK can restore it. So Helena, a stranger in a strange
>   land, embarks on an epic quest to find the missing charm before
>   darkness envelops the Dreamworld forever.*