# Tomboy girl befriends some clockwork robot and has an older sister who's evil and brainwashed her to wear makeup

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can't quite remember the name of this movie. Somewhere before 2010 but is probably older than that. It was either on Encore channel or HBO. I can only remember the film being very clockwork/steampunk themed with the robots or characters being all 3-D animated but the girl is live action. She dresses like a tomboy. At one point an older girl presumably her sister, brainwashed her somehow into putting on makeup and a dress.

Comment: One of these, possibly; [Wikpedia:List of films with live action and animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_with_live_action_and_animation)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is a bit terse. Going through the checklists here *([How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875))* would dramatically improve your question;

Comment: Could it be Oz-related? The elements of "clockwork robot" and a "girl changing from masculine to feminine" remind me of Tik-Tok and Ozma.

Comment: This sounds vaguely familiar. Was the dress overly floofy, and the makeup badly caked on?

Comment: The dress was indeed floofy and the makeup was badly caked on. Like queen Victoria style from what I remember. And if it's any help of all, the film was greatly yellow-hued with all warm tones. No blues or such from what I remember.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175670/fantasy-movie-with-black-and-white-queens

Answer (score 7):

This sounds something like [MirrorMask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MirrorMask), a Neil Gaiman-written movie from 2005. The main character, Helena, is pretty tomboyish and towards the end of the movie is hypnotized/brainwashed by an older woman (her parallel-universe "mother") into believing she's a princess. The movie uses a very consistent yellowish tone throughout the bulk of the runtime, resembling a mix of sepia-toned footage and the dull glow of sodium lamps, and there's a great deal of intentional haziness or heavy film grain for stylization purposes.

Helena and a few other characters are portrayed through live-action, while most of the rest are CGI, so that fits with your recollection. One character, Valentine, wears a mask that hinders facial expression and makes him *look* somewhat robotic but he's flesh-and-blood, so that's a slight difference.

[This site](http://mickiemuellerart.blogspot.com/2011/05/monday-night-magical-movie-mirrormask.html) has a bunch of pictures and a summary that might help ID the movie as what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Sid If my answer, or anyone else's who adds one, is the movie you're looking for, click the little checkmark under the vote counter to mark it as accepted.